# Can I do away with this highlighting in HTML?

Tags: html, css

Whenever we select some text, the entire text area gets highligted. like [this](http://www.freeimagehosting.net/image.php?bc23293797.jpg) .

but is there any way to do away with this highlighting? I want just the color of the text to change and not the area to be highlighted as it appears in the image? am  I clear enough?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Depends on which browsers you need to support. Not sure if Internet Explorer does support it, but here are the three CSS pseudo-elements you can try:

- ::selection (works in my Chrome)
- ::-moz-selection
- ::-webkit-selection

For example:

`p::selection {
    background:#cc0000;
    color:#fff;
}`

Also see http://www.quirksmode.org/css/selection.html

Answer (score 0):

<strike>If you're talking about when someone selects the text in the browser (using the mouse or shift-selecting) then this isn't possible.</strike>

[UPDATE]

I take it all back - as @Dev F and @nico say, there's a selection CSS3 property. (Of course only some browsers will support this, but...)

Comment: @Sachindra - I suspect that's just coincidence (in that the colour chosen by the browser/OS happened to match the background). In essence, there's no *standard* CSS property that let's you control this.

Comment: It can actually be done using the `::selection` selector (browser specific).